# Flutter chat application

Tags: flutter

I want check whether the message is reached to the destination in Firebase.
and Also include some features like double tik when the user receives the message and also sigle tik when user doesnt receive the message

Comment: Please post the things thats you've tried.
Reference this guide to ask better questions https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark this message as read on destination's app.